# Точки и отрезки

Tags: java, алгоритм

Добрый день!

Прошу помощи, т.к. уже 2-й день бьюсь над задачей, и мозги начинают закипать.

Задание аналогично этому [Задача с использованием алгоритмов сортировки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/365417/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8?rq=1)

Условие вкратце такое: дано N отрезков разной длины и M точек, необходимо подсчитать, скольким отрезкам может принадлежать каждая точка.

Алгоритм решения у меня следующий:

1. Разбиваем все отрезки на 2 массива - массив левых концов (leftArray), и массив правых(rightArray).
2. Сортируем их быстрой сортировкой.
3. В цикле получаем из ввода точку k и запускаем механизм поиска:

   - Находим количество чисел =< точки в leftArray
   - Находим количество чисел < точки в rightArray
   - В качестве результата выводим их разность по модулю

Все решение упирается в поиск - использовать нужно именно бинарный, т.к. в противном случае не укладывается по времени (дано не более 2-х секунд).

Подскажите, как можно исправить код методов поиска, для получения нужного результата.

```
public static int difference(int[] left, int[] right, int k){
    int i, j;
    i = first(left,0, left.length-1,k);
    j = last(right,0,right.length-1,k);
    return Math.abs(i-j) ;
}
// ищем кол-во чисел в массиве левых концов
public static int first(int[] arr, int low, int high, int k) { 
    if (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (k >= arr[mid] && (arr[mid + 1] > k || arr[mid] == 0))
            return mid;
        else if (k > arr[mid])
            return first(arr, (mid + 1), high, k);
        else
            return first(arr, low, (mid - 1), k);
    }
    return -1;
}
// ищем кол-во чисел в массиве правых концов
public static int last(int[] arr, int low, int high, int k){ 
    if(high >= low){
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        if (k > arr[mid] && (arr[mid+1] > k || mid == high-1))
            return mid;
        else if(k < arr[mid])
            return last(arr, low, (mid -1), k);
        else if (k > arr[mid])
            return last(arr, (mid + 1), high, k);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Концы отрезков могут быть разбросаны по числовой оси произвольным образом, поэтому напрашивается такой алгоритм.

1. Слейте начала и концы массивов в один упорядоченный массив с признаками начала и конца отрезка.
2. Пробегитесь по этому упорядоченному массиву в порядке возрастания и рекуррентно поставьте в соответствие каждой точке массива ответ задачи (т.е. для начала отрезка добавляйте 1, для конца отрезка вычитайте 1).
3. Ответ для каждой требуемой точки можно найти дихотомией по индексу полученного массива (а сравниваются, очевидно, координаты).

Comment: Позволю себе уточнить, что имеется ввиду разбить ось на отрезки с ценой. К примеру есть три отрезка с координатами [1,4], [2,5], [7-9]. Итого результатрирующий массив отрезков
     `[0-1] - цена 0,
     [1-2] - цена 1,
     [2-4] - цена 2,
     [4-5] - цена 1,
     [5-7] - цена 0,
     [7-9] - цена 1`
Отрезки с ценой 0 можно не писать в итоговый массив. А поиск проводить делением пополам (ведь массив упорядочен)

Comment: Если автору нужен перевод на другой язык, то это точный перевод. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Верно ли я понял, что в качестве результирующего массива можно использовать, к примеру кортеж (a,1)(b,0)(c,-1), где а - начало отрезка, b - точка, c - конец отрезка? Двигаемся по этому массиву, в порядке возрастания, и для каждой точки запоминаем значение сумм a и c, стоящих перед точкой. Это значение и будет числом отрезков, в которые входит точка.

Comment: Как промежуточный результат - да. Но в результирующем массиве хотелось бы видеть координаты (a,c) и уже подсчитанное количество отрезков. Это дало бы возможность провести для точки бинарный поиск (дихотомию) по индексам и сразу получить ответ.

Comment: решил проблему немного по-другому. как и писал раньше, слил все точки и отрезки в один массив с признаком типа, отсортировал его, прошел по этому массиву, изменяя счетчик, и на каждом значении точки, складывал эту точку и значение счетчика в map. затем проходил по массиву точек, который был получен при их вводе, и для каждого элемента получал из map значение по ключу.

Comment: Главное - что решил.

Comment: Хотя требование бинарности не выполнено. Я имел в виду что-то вроде этого: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_average_segment

Comment: Похожая ссылка http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/365417/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8?rq=1