# Java проверка интервала времени

Tags: java, дата

Есть список интервалов, c двумя полями начало и конца. Длина списка может быть от 1 до n

```
List<IntervalCalendare> period
```

нужно проверить все периоды пересекаются они или нет. Без использования двойных циклов.

И без сторонних библиотек, например вот так :

```
List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<App.Interval>();
intervals.add(new Interval("23.10.2017 10:00 Z", "23.10.2017 11:00 Z"));
intervals.add(new Interval("21.10.2017 10:30 Z", "25.10.2017 11:00 Z"));
intervals.add(new Interval("23.10.2017 10:20 Z", "23.10.2017 11:00 Z"));

// все пары пересечений     
List<Intercection> intercections = Interval.getIntercection(intervals);
intercections.forEach(inter -> System.out.println(inter.toString()));
```

Comment: Ваши предположения? мысли, код.

Comment: а реализация `Interval` какая? мне кажется что проще будет оперировать объектами `Date` а не строками

Comment: Можно и объектом, только как сравнить каждый с каждым, без использования двойного цикла

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @iksuy уххх. зачем же так... сразу...

Comment: Без двойных циклов, разве что, рекурсией.

Comment: Ребят почему минуса? достойный вопрос. И чертовски интересный

Comment: что-то вроде [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/365417/), только нужна не толщина покрытия в произвольной точке, а места, где толщина становится равной или неравной нулю.